# Set the driver for JDBI manually

Tags: java, mysql, jdbi

right now I'm writing a program in Java that will be plugged into an existing application as a plugin.
I want to use JDBI in my plugin (as it is very comfortable and I'm used to it) and need to connect to a MySQL database.

Usually that works fine after including the driver, but there is a problem with the existing application. Obviously it already has a mysql-driver, but an obsolete one.

That causes errors and makes it impossible to send a query to the database. (The error is known: The old driver has deprecated methods that cannot be used with the new MySQL versions)

I thought shading my jar would help (I'm using maven) but the error still occurs.
But I know the shaded name of my driver, I only need to know how to load it so JDBI will make use of it. Right now I have something like this:

```
Class.forName("myapp.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

DBI dbi = new DBI(String.format("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", username, password);
```

What do I have to do to tell jdbi it must use `myapp.mysql.jdbc.Driver`?

Comment: It is the protocol (`jdbc:mysql:`) that determines which driver gets a chance. Maybe you can patch "mysql" with "xxxxx" to use your own connection URLs. How does **MariaDB** sound, the MySQL fork?

Comment: Could you give an example? I can't really imagine what you mean...

Comment: Look at [Driver.acceptsURL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28169947/984823). By patching your driver (for instance as in that answer), you keep both drivers jdbc:mysql and jdbc:xxxxx separate. (Of course a DriverManager.unregister from the MySQL driver would be possible too.)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the `DataSource` api instead. You don't have to do `Class.forName` (which I find icky). The MySQL DataSource implementation has a `setUrl` method that takes `jdbc:mysql://...`. Then you can just pass the `DataSource` to the `DBI`. Here's an example:

```
MysqlDataSource ds = new MysqlDataSource();
ds.setUrl(dbUrl);
DBI dbi = new DBI(ds);
```