# DSS cannot connect to different Oracle database versions

Tags: wso2, oracle12c, wso2-data-services-server, oracle8i

I'm using the WSO2 Data Services (3.5.1) Server to connect with some Oracle 12c databases. However, to support the legacy, I also need to connect  to different versions like 10g and 8i.

There's the problem, using the `ojdbc14.jar` driver, the datasources:
`8i` works
`10g` works
`12c` gives: `ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol` (due the changes of SHA algorithm in the version 12)

Using the `ojdbc6.jar` or `ojdbc7.jar`:
`10g` works
`12c` works
`8i` gives:

```
org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.common.DataSourceException: Error establishing data source connection: 4  
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: 4
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:290)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:702)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.<init>(T4C8TTIdty.java:491)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1434)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
...
```

Searching for solution, I've found some alternative, by setting the parameter `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8` in the oracle/network/admin/sqlnet.ora file in the 12c database and using `ojdbc14.jar`, but due infrastructure restrictions, this approach is not acceptable.

I would like to know if there's a way to use simultaneously both drivers in DSS, maybe specifying some custom Java class extending the different `OracleDriver` class, and configuring the DSS class loader... or some different solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known backward compatibility limitation[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167594/using-multiple-oracle-jdbc-drivers-in-one-java-application), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597613/handle-multiple-jdbc-drivers-from-the-same-vendor) in oracle drivers and there's no solution in wso2 DSS as a workaround. This has clearly stated in  [Oracle version compatibility matrix](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_client_versions_higher_lower_database_release.htm).

Have you tried different versions of older ojdbc drivers which might work on both oracle versions(eg: oracle driver 10). Of cause not all the features might work, but you might end up with connecting to all the databases and execute basics without issue.